# How to enable a button after fill up some edittext filed

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-button

I have some text field. And I want to enable a submit button after entering value into the all the text field. I tried.Is any one can suggest what to do!!!
Here is my code I wrote it onto my onCreate method.

```
        confrimPasswordButton.setEnabled(false);
        passCheck = confirmPasswordText.getText().toString();
        passwordNew = newPasswordText.getText().toString();
        passwordExist = exstingPasswordText.getText().toString();
```

Comment: add textwatcher to each edit text... and check all Edit text having some Value

Comment: have you solved this problem ? or still there is some issue left ?

Answer (score 2):

You should implement a [TextWatcher](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/TextWatcher.html). Pick one of three interface methods that suits you better and pass your implementation to the `EditText` through [addTextChangedListener()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#addTextChangedListener(android.text.TextWatcher)). If you're stuck with implementation - there are lots of resources on the Internet on how to implement a `TextWatcher`.

Answer (score 0):

**Add the `TextWatcher` to your `EditText` like this**

```
passwordEditText.addTextChangedListener(passwordWatcher);
```

**Here is the `passwordWatcher`**

```
private TextWatcher passwordWatcher = new TextWatcher() {
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

    }

    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
     if(//password matches with value of edittext){

        button.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE); // Make your button visible
          }
    }

    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
        if (s.length() == 0) {
            button.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        } else{
            //code to show some some error
        }
    }
};
```

}

**NOTE : Follow the pattern, Copy and pasting may cause some error because i didn't check the codes.**

Answer (score 0):

Check below solution

```
    passwordExist.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3) {            

    }
        @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1, int arg2,
                    int arg3) {             
    }
    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable et) {

      if((passwordExist.getText().length()>0)
      {
       button.setVisibility(View.GONE); ///PERFROM ACTION WHAT EVER YOU WANT TO DO WHEN EDIT TEXT LENGTH GREATER THAN 0
      }
      else{
       button.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);///PERFROM ACTION WHAT EVER YOU WANT TO DO WHEN EDIT TEXT LENGTH EQUAL TO 0
     }

    }
});
```